# check date in php not working with different month

Tags: php, html, mysql

here i am checking the date with current date to previous date it show the proper message when the subtracted date's result is current date .but when the subtracted result is previous date like 02-12-2014 - 4 days it gives 28-11-2014 .and condition of (02-12-2014>=28-11-2014) it gives false.why it cant check the diff of diff month's date. even it true the condition when date like (04-12-2014>=06-12-2014).

```
<div class="box-content">
    <div class="maq_cont">
        <marquee direction="up" scrollamount="3" onMouseOut="this.setAttribute('scrollamount',3,0)" onMouseOver="this.setAttribute('scrollamount', 0, 0)" style="height:200px; margin-top:-10px;  margin-bottom:-10px;">
            <ul class="maq_li">
            <?php
                echo $work_date = "03-12-2014";
                echo "<br>";
                echo $day = "3";
                echo "<br>";                                        
                echo $show_date = date( "d-m-Y", strtotime( "$work_date -$day day" ));
                echo "<br>";
                echo $cur_date= date( "d-m-Y" );

                if ($cur_date >= $show_date) {
                    echo '<li>done</li>';
                } else {
                    echo '<li>not done</li>';
                }
            ?>
            </ul>
        </marquee>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with -

```
if(strtotime($cur_date)>=strtotime($show_date)){
```

It is happening because they are `strings`.

Comment: You can also do it with string but change the format string to `date('Y-m-d');`... With this format they are correctly sortable... But @sgt's solution is much better...

Comment: yes we can..for the above format they are first converted to `int` i think thats why this is happening.

Comment: no they are still strings. But sortable because the year is the first value of the string. It will first sort by year, then month and then days. In the question `user3300358` first sorts by day, and if day of `$cur_date` is smaller then the day of `$show_date`, the string comparison told him, the date is smaller. but the year of `$cur_date` could already be greater then the year of `$show_date`. So you make mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the year at the beginning of your date string, then month and then the day. The reason is: You aren't comparing dates, you compare string. And they will be compared alphabetically.

e.g. the string date `'01.01.2015'` is alphabetically smaller than `'02.01.2013'`, but this format (`'Ymd'`) does the trick in this special order: `'20150101'` is alphabetically and also numerically greater than `'20130102'`.

```
// this formatting will work
$show_date = date('Ymd', strtotime("$work_date -$day day"));
$cur_date = date('Ymd');
```

I would prefer to do this comparison with date and the awesome `DateTime` object. Do it like this:

```
if (new DateTime('NOW')
    >= DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $show_date))
{
    echo '<li>done</li>';
} else {
    echo '<li>not done</li>';
}
```

The `DateTime::createFromFormat()` call returns a `DateTime` object. The first parameter `$format` has the same syntax like your format string you are using with `date()`. The second parameter is the so formatted date string to parse. Read more:

- http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

---

After getting this `DateTime` object you can do some magic like

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $show_date);

$date->modify('+1 days'); // one day later
```

And to output the date as string use the `format()`function:

```
$date->format('Y'); // the year
$date->format('m'); // the month
$date->format('d'); // the day
$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // e.g. 2014-12-05 23:11:00
$date->format('U'); // as timestamp: 1417817460
// [...]
```

More Information:

- http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php